# C segfault when looping over a list

Tags: c, list, pointers, while-loop, segmentation-fault

Here is my list struct:

```
typedef struct Header {
  struct Header* next;
  char empty;
  int storageSize;
} Header;
```

And I am looping over a list to check how many elements its has:

```
int listSize(Header* _header) {
  int count = 0;
  while(_header->next) {
    _header = _header->next;
    ++count;
  }

  return count;
}
```

And I get a segfault after reaching the end of the list.
However if I change it to:

```
int listSize(Header* _header) {
  int count = 0;
  while(_header->next) {
    if(!_header->next) {
      _header = _header->next;
      ++count;
    }
    else
      break;
  }

  return count;
}
```

It doesn't segfault, but it also obviously doesn't count the elements right.

Comment: Use a debugger. And if you really need help after exhausting all other debugging efforts then provide a [mcve].

Comment: I used lldb, but it doesn't segfault when use it.

Comment: Could you add how you build your list?

Comment: I think `while(_header->next) {` should be `while(_header) {`

Comment: You won't pass the case where you pass `NULL` to `listSize()`.

Comment: @BenSmith your edit makes all the comments/answers so far pretty much useless, and you are actually asking a  new question, *without* providing a minimal example of your code. Please take a moment understanding what you have been told here, and if needed, post a new question, with an improved version of your code and a **minimal example**. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
while(_header->next) {
```

to this:

```
while(_header) {
```

since you want to loop over your list, as long as the *current* node is not `NULL`.

You were facing a segmentation fault, because you were trying to get the `next` data member of `NULL`.

It feels like you are passing an **empty list** to your `listSize()`, that is that the `_header` is `NULL`, and you are trying to get the `next` data member of `NULL`, thus a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, in [tag:C++] at least [it's not common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), and you can see [tag:c] traits on that one...

Answer (score 0):

You logic is incorrect. The code should be this - and note the comments

```
int listSize(Header* header) {
  int count = 0;
    while (header) {             // We have a node to count
      ++count;                   // Count it
      header = header->next;     // And move to the next node 
    }

   return count;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you can initialize `next` as 0 or `*next` as 0 whenever you want to create a new node.